Apple VoIP Notifications Not Working Background
I have an app which I have enabled VoIP entitlement and implemented all the CallKit and PushKit registries and delegates.
I can successfully get a VoIP token.
I can successfully send VoIP push notifications (and receive them via the PushKit delegate function) and then report an incoming call via CallKit, but only while my app is in the foreground.
I have checked the entitlement in XCode and the Info.plist directly, and they both (as expected) show voip as a background mode.
The VoIP notification is being sent via AWS SNS and everything works while the app is in the foreground. I cannot understand why the app is not waking up while in the background.
This is the VoIP notification sent via SNS:
aps: {
        alert: "Intercom call",
        "content-available": 1
}

SNS Message Attributes:
                   'AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.TOPIC': {
                      DataType: 'String',
                      StringValue: `${bundleId}`
                    },
                    'AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.PUSH_TYPE': {
                        DataType: 'String',
                        StringValue: 'voip'
                    },
                    'AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS_VOIP.TTL': {
                        DataType: 'String',
                        StringValue: '0'
                    },
                    'AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS_VOIP_SANDBOX.TTL': {
                        DataType: 'String',
                        StringValue: '0'
                    },
                    'AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.PRIORITY': {
                        DataType: 'String',
                        StringValue: '10'
                    }

As I say,
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType) async
works correctly when in the foreground. I cannot see any reason why it would not work from the background.
I am also receiving normal remote notifications correctly foreground and background.
Checking the console (console.app), I am seeing (when in the background)
VoIP push for app <private> dropped on the floor.
What could be the reason for this?
If it is significant, I am seeing the messages in pairs.
I.e. at the same time (bar milliseconds)
VoIP push for app <private> dropped on the floor
VoIP push for app <private> dropped on the floor

in the console.app window even though I am only ever receiving a single VoIP (as correctly working in foreground).

Same here. Did you manage to resolve this?

@BinhHo Seems this log just means the phone has banned itself from passing VoIP messages. It can take up to 24 hours for it to 'unban' itself.

@BinhHo When I tried, it was very picky about how much of the payload I could iterate through before deciding to drop it. It seems, whatever you do, report the call. You can update the details after the fact with a function in the CallProvider class.
